# SSRS - Multiple Groups to display data

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We have a SharePoint List with following columns:

```html
Dep User Start Date End Date Status
D1 U1 03/08/2015 09/08/2015 RED
D1 U1 10/08/2015 16/08/2015 GREEN
D1 U1 17/08/2015 23/08/2015 YELLOW
D1 U1 24/08/2015 30/08/2015 BLUE
D1 U2 03/08/2015 09/08/2015 GREEN
D1 U2 10/08/2015 16/08/2015 GREEN
D1 U2 24/08/2015 30/08/2015 RED
D2 U3 03/08/2015 09/08/2015 YELLOW
D2 U3 24/08/2015 30/08/2015 YELLOW
D2 U4 17/08/2015 23/08/2015 BLUE
D2 U4 24/08/2015 30/08/2015 RED
D3 U5 10/08/2015 16/08/2015 YELLOW
D3 U6 03/08/2015 09/08/2015 BLUE
D3 U6 10/08/2015 16/08/2015 RED
D3 U6 17/08/2015 23/08/2015 BLUE
D3 U6 24/08/2015 30/08/2015 GREEN
```

We want to create report in following format:

```html
Dep User Week 1 Week 2 Week 3 Week 4
D1 U1 RED GREEN YELLOW BLUE
 U2 GREEN GREEN  RED
D2 U3 YELLOW  YELLOW 
 U4   BLUE RED
D3
D3 U5  YELLOW  
 U6 BLUE RED BLUE GREEN
```

What we have come up till now is:

```html
Departments User  8/3/2015 8/10/2015  8/17/2015  8/24/2015 
D1         U10     GREEN   
                    RED 
         U12                             RED   
           YELLOW  
                    BLUE 
                             GREEN
         U13     RED   
                                                YELLOW
```

Any idea to bring all status in one row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a Matrix, with two row groups.

1. Create the matrix, and set the row to be the Dep field.
2. Right click the row and select `Add Group` -> `Child Group`.  Set this child group to be the User Name
3. Set the column headers to be the Start dates
4. Finally set the Data to be the status.

The final matrix should look as follows

[image]

And will give this result when run

[image]

I'm sure once you get to this stage you will be able to do some tinkering to label the columns as you want them, or format it differently when required.

Comment: Worked. Thanks @Jonnus
Also, if we need to add a column like User Designation next to User name, how to proceed?

Comment: Does each user only have one User Designation?  If not then another child row group would be best.  If it does only have the one then you could right click the column header for `[Start]`.  Select `Insert Column` -> `Outside Group - Left` and put the User Designation in there.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Tried but not working. Empty report with first three columns and [Start] column is not appearing.